# How to host Swagger documentation using yaml/json configuration files?

Tags: spring-boot, configuration, yaml, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

```java
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig2 extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public SwaggerResourcesProvider swaggerResourcesProvider() {
        return () -> {
            SwaggerResource wsResource = new SwaggerResource();
            wsResource.setName("Documentation");
            wsResource.setSwaggerVersion("2.0");
            wsResource.setLocation("/swagger.yaml");

            List<SwaggerResource> resources = List.of(wsResource);
            return resources;
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/swagger.yaml").addResourceLocations("classpath:/swagger.yaml");
    }

}
```

i m trying add my swagger.yaml custom file in swagger configuration for add in swagger ui, but when i call url "http://localhost:8078/swagger-ui.html#/" i got "Failed to load API definition." and "Fetch errorundefined http://localhost:8078/swagger.yaml" so how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static final String[] PUBLIC_URLS = {"/employee/add","/employee/register","/employee/login", "/swagger-ui.html/**", "/v2/api-docs", "/swagger-resources/**"
        , "/webjars/**", "/v3/api-docs", "/googledocs/**" ,"/swagger-apis/**"};
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
    .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(PUBLIC_URLS).permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();

    http.addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    return http.build();
}
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2 public class SwaggerConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean
public Docket apiDocket() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2);
}

@Primary
@Bean
public SwaggerResourcesProvider swaggerResourcesProvider(
        InMemorySwaggerResourcesProvider defaultResourcesProvider) {
    return () -> {
        List<SwaggerResource> resources = new ArrayList<>();
        Arrays.asList("api1", "api2", "api3").forEach(resourceName -> resources.add(loadResource(resourceName)));
        return resources;
    };
}

private SwaggerResource loadResource(String resource) {
    SwaggerResource wsResource = new SwaggerResource();
    wsResource.setName(resource);
    wsResource.setSwaggerVersion("2.0");
    wsResource.setLocation("/swagger-apis/" + resource + "/swagger.yaml");
    return wsResource;
}

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/swagger-apis/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/swagger-apis/")
    .setCachePeriod(0);
}
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).